# Вопрос по абстрагированию JavaScript

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Всем привет. Изучаю JavaScript, читаю учебник "Выразительный JavaScript" и дошел до интересной задачи в конце пятой главы.

Задание выглядит так:

> В качестве призовой игры напишите функцию groupBy, абстрагирующую операцию группировки. Она должна принимать массив и функцию, которая вычисляет группу для элементов массива, и возвращать объект, который сопоставляет названия групп массивам членов этих групп.

Я решил что буду писать прототипированный метод для массивов, чтобы в функцию массив передавался как `массив.метод()`

В общем вот код, он работает прекрасно, всё как нужно отрабатывает. Принёс Вам его на суд, что Вы скажете? Есть какие-то явные огрехи и говнокод?

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(acto) {

    var tempObj = {}; //Создаем пустой объект
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++){ //Запускаем проход по массиву
        var temp = acto(this[i]); //Создаём переменную, куда помещаем результат вызова функции переданной аргументом. Условимся о том, что функция, передаваемая аргументом, должна возвращать строку
        if (!tempObj[temp]) { //Проверяем наш объект и если в нём нет свойства с таким именем, то 
            tempObj[temp] = [this[i]]; //Создаём свойство с таким именем куда помещаем массив, в который, в свою очередь, помещаем элемент итерации
        } else { //Иначе
            tempObj[temp].push(this[i]); //в массив-свойство объекта добавляем результат операции
        }
    }
    return tempObj; //Возвращаем объект

}
```

Пример работы:

```js
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(acto) {
  var tempObj = {}; //Создаем пустой объект
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { //Запускаем проход по массиву
    var temp = acto(this[i]); //Создаём переменную, куда помещаем результат вызова функции переданной аргументом. Условимся о том, что функция, передаваемая аргументом, должна возвращать строку
    if (!tempObj[temp]) { //Проверяем наш объект и если в нём нет свойства с таким именем, то 
      tempObj[temp] = [this[i]]; //Создаём свойство с таким именем куда помещаем массив, в который, в свою очередь, помещаем элемент итерации
    } else { //Иначе
      tempObj[temp].push(this[i]); //в массив-свойство объекта добавляем результат операции
    }
  }
  return tempObj; //Возвращаем объект
}


var arrayWithTrash = [1, 2, 3, "A", "B", "C", 4, 5, 6, true, [1, 2, 3], {
  "a": 250
}];

console.log(
  arrayWithTrash.groupBy(function(elemArray) {
    if (typeof elemArray === "number") return "Number";
    else if (typeof elemArray === "string") return "String";
    else if (typeof elemArray === "boolean") return "Boolean";
    else return "Other";
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, добавлять перечисляемое свойство в массив - ужасная идея! Как минимум, его следует сделать неперечисляемым. Для этого можно использовать [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "groupBy", {
  value: function (acto) {
    // ...
  },
});
```

Во-вторых, лучше давать переменным понятные названия. Не `acto`, `temp`, `tempObj` - а `keySelector`, `key`, `result`.

В-третьих, у вас будут баги с такими ключами, как `toString`. Чтобы создаваемый пустой объект был реально пустым - надо использовать не `{}`, а `Object.create(null)`.

В-четвертых, большинство методов массива передают в callback вторым аргументом индекс элемента в массиве, а третьим - сам массив. Возможно, вам стоит ради красоты сделать так же - это же ничего не стоит.

Comment: Интересно, создавая объект через Object.create(null) у него нет свойства __proto__, а через {} - есть. Что это значит?

Comment: 1) Прототип встроенного объекта вообще не стоит трогать. Это вотчина создателей движка. 2) Если они в двух строках, то необязательно. Хотя, конечно, мысль стоящая. 3) Какие баги? Собственные свойства их не содержат, а может понадобится метод прототипа объекта. 4) Хорошая идея :)

Comment: @ДенисИванов, `Object.create(null)` - это редкий способ сделать пустой прототип, чтобы даже `Object` не находился в предках. `{}` - обычное создание объекта, который наследует `Object`.

Comment: @Other будет ошибка при попытке сделать вот так: `tempObj["toString"].push(this[i])` - у функции нет метода push!

Comment: Не согласен. Ключ должен добавится со значением массива.

Comment: И еще вопрос: почему перечисляемые свойства это ужасно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, для этого случая у него как раз `if (!tempObj[temp]) { tempObj[temp] = [this[i]];` и в случае с `toString` он его просто сделает полем

Comment: @ДенисИванов, потому что могут неожиданно всплыть в цикле

Comment: А с точки зрения безопасности?

Comment: @Grundy функция - это истинное значение, а не ложное. Эта ветка не будет выполняться для `toString`

Comment: @Other ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а вот про это я что-то не подумал :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот Вы про что. Тогда `Object#hasOwnProperty` поможет.

Comment: @Other все равно получается некрасиво. Иногда вроде как toString - массив, а иногда - метод. Прямо-таки вечный источник багов...

Comment: @Other лучше если есть хоть 1 шанс что toString будет перезаписан массивом - убрать значение по умолчанию совсем

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это специфика JS - ходить по острию :) Впрочем, я не настаиваю, можно и зануллить предка.

Answer (score 1):

Забавная задачка.
Но простая, поэтому код тоже простой, оптимизировать нечего особо (разве что добавить проверок на входные данные).
Изменять/добавлять прототипы встроенных объектов - плохо, не делайте этого.

```js
const groupBy = (a, fn, full = {}) => a.forEach((e, _) => (_ = fn(e) + '') && (full.hasOwnProperty(_) ? full[_].push(e) : full[_] = [e])) || full;

var arrayWithTrash = [1, 2, 3, "A", "B", "C", 4, 5, 6, true, [1, 2, 3], {a: 250}],
    fn = function(elemArray) {
  if (typeof elemArray === "number") return "Number";
  else if (typeof elemArray === "string") return "String";
  else if (typeof elemArray === "boolean") return "Boolean";
  else return "Other";
};

console.info(groupBy(arrayWithTrash, fn));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: _огромные массивы лучше чанками обрабатывать_ - чем это лучше в яваскрипте? и сделай тогда уж пример

Comment: @Grundy, обработка больших данных может надолго занять процесс и браузер может предложить убить его. А кусочками может и пойдёт. Пример... Ну а почему бы и нет?

Comment: @Grundy, пойдёт?

Comment: Теперь осталось только сделать _огромный_ массив и проверить, действительно ли будет выгода, от этой функции

Comment: @Grundy, давайте и это проверим, если есть желание.

Comment: @Grundy, проверил. Сильно я ошибался :) Раз в 50.

Comment: Эм? без разбития быстрее или что? Возможно с разбитием может быть быстрее, если каждую часть запихивать в вебворкер. Ну и опять же все от размера исходного массива зависит

Comment: @Grundy, Массив на 100.000 элементов (все типы рандомно напихал): цельно: 30ms, делил на кусочки (1000): >8.000ms.

Comment: скорее всего просто код с делением ужасно неоптимален :-)

Comment: @Grundy, Возможно, хотел сделать функционально и вычурно, хоть и страшно, вместо `while(a.length > chLen) chArr.push(a.splice(0, chLen));`. В любом случае проигрывает ощутимо.